# Split PHP Echo into two Code snippets

Tags: php

I wish to break a PHP Code into two areas where it gets shown without duplicating its content.

I have shortened the code a bit to make it easier to read and so i don't need to rewrite all the url and domains snippets in it.

The PHP Code is used with a second one in the head where i have to define what niche and amount of items to show.

I would like to Show 8 items ($xxlimit = 8;) thats the easy part, but can I split the script somehow into 2 times 4 items? So that i can show above a posting 4 and above the posting again 4.

```
<?php
$i = 0;
foreach ($xinfos as $xinfo) {
    foreach ($xinfo as $key => $value) {
        if (is_numeric($value)) {
            $value = (int) $value;
        } else {
            if (!is_array($value)) {
                $value = (string) $value;
            }
        }
        $$key = $value;
    }
    $previewurl   = 'http://' . $xx_server . '/images/' . $id . '_1_' . $image_size . '.jpg';
    $previewurl_2 = 'http://' . $xx_server . '/images/' . $id . '_2_' . $image_size . '.jpg';
    echo ('<div style="width:16%; float: left;"><a href="http://' . $xx_url . '"> <img src="' . $previewurl . '" alt="' . $name . '"> </a></div>' . "\n");
    $i++;
    if ($i == $xxlimit) {
        break;
    }
}
?>
```

Having the echo displayed 4 times, adding this break or something, adding my site and then the script continues with 4 echos.

Somehow i believe that must be kind of easy (if I had only the right 'keyword' to know what i must search)

Help would be really appreciated.

Edit:

The code i have right now is the code i had shown already here. And as it was mentioned in the comment it was already hard to understand what i wished to to, so i have tried to explain visually

```
-------------   -------------   -------------   -------------
|           |   |           |   |           |   |           |
|           |   |           |   |           |   |           |
|  Object 1 |   |  Object 2 |   |  Object 3 |   |  Object 4 |
|           |   |           |   |           |   |           |
|           |   |           |   |           |   |           |
-------------   -------------   -------------   -------------

-------------------------------------------------------------
|                                                           |
|                                                           |
|  Display here now some other Content that is NOT related  |
|  to the Objects before and continue AFTER this where      |
|  it had stopped (after the first four Objects) and        |
|  display the remaining objects as declared                |
|  with $xxlimit = 8                                        |
|                                                           |
|                                                           |
-------------------------------------------------------------

-------------   -------------   -------------   -------------
|           |   |           |   |           |   |           |
|           |   |           |   |           |   |           |
|  Object 5 |   |  Object 6 |   |  Object 7 |   |  Object 8 |
|           |   |           |   |           |   |           |
|           |   |           |   |           |   |           |
-------------   -------------   -------------   -------------
```

Comment: It's difficult to understand what you're trying to do.  Perhaps you could type up the output you want to see so people can compare it to the code you've written.

Comment: I have tried to explain it different. Sadly i do have no other code than that to explain it.. somehow i had hoped it would be something really simple.. I had hoped there is some kind of wait/continue command that might could have been used or so :(

Answer (score 2):

You can use `array_slice` to select the first/last 4 rows and pass them to a function that displays them

```
print_xinfos(array_slice($xinfos,0,4));
print_posting();
print_xinfos(array_slice($xinfos,3,4));

function print_xinfos ($xinfos) {
    foreach ($xinfos as $xinfo) {
        foreach ($xinfo as $key => $value) {
            if (is_numeric($value)) {
                $value = (int) $value;
            } else {
                if (!is_array($value)) {
                    $value = (string) $value;
                }
            }
            $$key = $value;
        }
        $previewurl   = 'http://' . $xx_server . '/images/' . $id . '_1_' . $image_size . '.jpg';
        $previewurl_2 = 'http://' . $xx_server . '/images/' . $id . '_2_' . $image_size . '.jpg';
        echo ('<div style="width:16%; float: left;"><a href="http://' . $xx_url . '"> <img src="' . $previewurl . '" alt="' . $name . '"> </a></div>' . "\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: Would it be possible to use it then like `print_xinfos(array_slice($xinfos,0,4));
print_posting(HERE I ENTER MY HTML CODE AND EVERYTHING);
print_xinfos(array_slice($xinfos,3,4));` this?